# WebView Reference is Null When Calling Parent Method From Child Class

Tags: java, android, inheritance, webview, parent-child

When I call the parent method from the child class the WebView reference is null and I can't figure out why or how to fix. Thank you in advance for your help!

Example Parent Class:

```
public class ParentClass extends Activity {

public WebView MyWebView;

@Override
protected onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MyWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.MyWebView);
};

public void MyParentMethod(String sURL) {
    //This "MyWebView" reference is null and nothing happens when called from child class???
    MyWebView.loadUrl(sURL);
};

};
```

Example Child Class:

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

    public void MyChildMethod() {
        super.MyParentMethod("...");
    };

};
```

Comment: where u are using `ChildClass` class?

Comment: Check if you can directly call MyParentMethod() in Child class.(without super)

Comment: When i call the method directly `MyParentMethod()` (without super) I get an NPE error. 

I am using `ChildClass` because I have 2 compiled jar libraries for 2 different pieces of integrated hardware the caveat is that both libraries use handling methods with the duplicate names. Sub classing allows me to keep those methods separated.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `MyParentMethod()` of `ParentClass` with `super` keyword?

`super` keyword is usually used when the `ChildClass` members and `ParentClass` members (method/variables) have same name.

You can call **ParentClass method** just with the **method name** (if the `ChildClass` doesn't have same method) as the method also belongs to the ChildClass, like `methodName(arguments)`.

So, you should replace this `super.MyParentMethod("...");` with either `new ParentClass().MyParentMethod("...");` or with `MyParentMethod("...");`.

Comment: I tried calling the parent method in both recommended ways `new ParentClass().MyParentMethod("...");` and `MyParentMethod("...");` . Both returned **NPE**. Again, when i call using "super" the method works however, the original reference is null.